# Why my function can't see this arrays strings

Tags: php

Please help me find bug in my code.
Why my function can't see varaibles, which is holded outside function?

```
    $file['folder'] = "/files/"; 
    $file['file'] = "myFile.txt";
    $file['ip'] = "http://127.0.0.1:1234";

function patToFile($sql,$action){
    $path = $file['ip'] . "/" . $file['folder'] . "/" . $file['file'];
    return $path;
}
```

When I use `pathTofile();` it returns "//". So it cant see variable outside.

1. Why?
2. How I can fix this?

**EDIT:**
I'm using `global $file;` inside function, to tell function use global variables.

Comment: 1. Read about the [scope of variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in PHP. 2. Pass the array as argument to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**

```
$file['folder'] = "/files/"; 
$file['file'] = "myFile.txt";
$file['ip'] = "http://127.0.0.1:1234";

function patToFile($sql,$action,$file){
    $path = $file['ip'] . "/" . $file['folder'] . "/" . $file['file'];
    return $path;
}

//Call function, Suppose already $sql, $action
pathToFile($sql, $action, $file);
```

**Method 2** using `$GLOBALS` if variable `$file` is global variable

```
$file['folder'] = "/files/"; 
$file['file'] = "myFile.txt";
$file['ip'] = "http://127.0.0.1:1234";

function patToFile($sql,$action){
    $path = $GLOBALS['file']['ip'] . "/" . $GLOBALS['file']['folder'] . "/" . $GLOBALS['file']['file'];
    return $path;
}

//Call function, Suppose already $sql, $action
pathToFile($sql, $action);
```

Comment: I'm using in function `global $file` and it makes array visible for function. Thank You for answer! :)

Comment: Yes, At first I was going to write the same way but I changed my mind to use `$GLOBALS`, but they are same

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
function patToFile($sql,$action) use ($file){
    $path = $GLOBALS['file']['ip'] . "/" . $GLOBALS['file']['folder'] . "/" . $GLOBALS['file']['file'];
    return $path;
}
```